# Use Tshark to view json data

Tags: json, wireshark, tcpdump, tshark

When I use tshark to decode capfile like this

```
 tshark -V -r test.cap  -Y 'http>0'
```

I got

```
...
JavaScript Object Notation: application/json
    Object
        Member Key: "ret"
            Number value: 99
        Member Key: "message"
            String value:test
```

Question is how I can get json data like that use tshark

```
...
{"ret":99,"message":"test"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tshark -r test.cap  -Y 'http>0' -T json

tshark -r test.cap  -Y 'http>0' -T json -x # to also include the raw packet data
```

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem.
Failed to solved it with wireshark/tshark options only.
Below is my workaround for extracting **raw json and xml** from cap files.

```
# 1. convert to pdml with DISABLED json and xml dissectors
tshark -r "wireshark.cap" -2 -R "http" --disable-protocol json --disable-protocol xml -V -T pdml > "wireshark.cap.pdml.xml" 

# 2. get hex encoded raw data from media.type pdml element
# 3. perform hex decode
```

I used **groovy** script for steps 2 and 3

```
import groovy.xml.*

...

def String hexDecode(String s) {
    if ( null == s || 0 == s.length() ) { 
            return null
    }   
    def res = ""
    for (int i = 0; i < s?.length(); i += 2) {
            res += (Character)((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16))
    }   
    return res 
}

...

def xmlFile = new File("wireshark.cap.pdml.xml")
def pdml  = new XmlParser().parseText( xmlFile.text )
pdml.packet.each{ packet->
    def media = packet.proto.find{ "media"==it.@name }
    def hex  = media?.field.find{"media.type"==it.@name }?.@value
    def raw = hexDecode(hex)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what "how I can get json data like that use tshark" means.  The JavaScript info you saw when you ran tshark looks like that because tshark parses application/json bodies as JSON and displays the JSON information in pretty output like you see.  If you don't want it to do that, you'd need to disable the JSON protocol/dissector; unfortunately I don't believe there is a way to disable protocols in tshark, but there is in wireshark (go to menu Analyze->Enabled Protocols and uncheck the JSON one).

Comment: I don't know how to use tshark export http objects,just like wireshark does,that's what I want

Comment: Oh you mean the menu File->Export Objects->HTTP feature. That's only available in wireshark as far as I know. For tshark, you can try one of the '-T' options.  Or parse what the '-V' option outputs.